# How to integrate InMobi ads to android App (Using AdMob)

Tags: android, admob, ads, inmobi

I'm new at advertising stuff, I'm using AdMob to publish advertising with my app. Now i want to add InMobi advertising, but i'm little confused, i registered InMobi and it has android integration informations. Should i integrate the code to my app or is it enough to write `App Id`, `Login Name`, `Passoword`, `Secret Key` in AdMob `Edit Mediation` section. if it is enough how can i get these informations. Hope I could explain myself. Thanks in advance.

I use these codes to show advertising :

```
    adView = new AdView(MainActivity.this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("MY_ID");
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adv);
    layout.addView(adView);

    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice(deviceid).build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integration of *InMobi* into *AdMob* should be pretty simple. [Here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation-networks) is the link to the oficial docs. In short, you should download *InMobi* SDK **AND** adapter for *AdMob* from *InMobi* website (urls are in the *AdMob* docs), add downloaded SDK and adapter as libraries to your project, make corresponding changes in `AndroidManifest.xml` (add *InMobi's* activities, other *InMmobi* stuff described in the *InMobi* docs) and enable *InMobi* option in *AdMob* console. You should not use your *InMobi* credentials, all is done through *AdMob* credentials.

Comment: Thank you very much, i needed this answer to go forward.

Comment: Thanks, simple and to the point. Official InMobi docs could be clearer. Mediation instructions fail to even mention that their whole SDK is required as well, very confusing if already using adMob.

Comment: You mean to say that if i have admob already implemented then, apart from manifest changes and adding the libraries, I dont need to do any code changes ?